# How to load new page with transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to load external webpages withe preloaders when links are clicked, something like after clicking MetroUI in the site:

http://www.melonhtml5.com/

But with a complete different page / external link.

So far I was trying to do it with jquery by using:

```
$(function() {
    $("#changepage").click(function() {
        $("#preloader").show();        
        $('body').load('./anotherPage.html');

        return false;
    });
});
```

But it only loads content without css styling. New page is a html game, so also need new js imports, etc.

Including them in different divs on same file is not an option.

How can I achieve this?

Regards

Comment: He/she is using single page architecture. Using backbone.js would help you accomplish this. Do you know backbone.js? You can see the hash in the url `#!/royal_preloader` this is a way to call a view and render it within the DOM.

Comment: Best way to see what is happening to the content is to open the developer tools and then click a box, you see all the HTML is the same except some HTML changes inside `#widget_preview`. You don't necessarily need backbone, but it would make it easier. The developer is pretty much hiding HTML then displaying it when a box is clicked. Maybe the script metro.js the developer is using http://www.melonhtml5.com/javascript/metro.js has this functionality http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs

Comment: Another way to achieve this, and possibly the way I am considering is just to load the external page regularly but do a little programmatic transition, set opacity to 0 on external pages then on some kind of callback or random amount of time 0.8s or whatever transition the body's opacity to 1.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know about backbone.js, was indeed wondering about that #! as I have seen them before but didn't knew what they were. Still open to suggestions, but thanks for the pointers.

Comment: It's called hash state I think and just triggers an event instead of actually making an HTTP request. It's meant for single page architecture. Honestly those are your options, render HTML on the same page based on what the user selects or make the HTTP request to a new page but add a transition. If your pages are optimized and load fast it will feel like single page architecture. I am all ears if someone has another solution, but I doubt it.